# Correct "hat" notation for a prediction from a GLM

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

Generally for a linear regression we write the estimator as $\hat{y}$ -- eg, $\hat{y} = f(\hat{\beta},x)$

What is the equivalent notation for a logistic regression?

Is it $\hat{p}(Y=1|X=x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say $\hat{p}$ where

$$\hat{p} = Pr( Y=1 \vert X = x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + \exp({-x^T \hat{\beta}})}$$

We call 
$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + \exp({-x})} $$

the logistic function.

[image]

Comment: Ok so not $\hat{p}=\hat{P}(Y=1|X=x)$?

Comment: P hat is probability. It doesn't make sense to put a hat on the probability operator.

Comment: But how about $\hat{P(Y=1|X=x)}$ (over the full expression)

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't matter so long as you are consistent and explain any non-standard notation.

Comment: It's however you want to notate it, as long as the reader is clear what each symbol stands for.

Comment: Disagree - shouldn't it be at least $$\hat{p} = Pr( Y=1 \vert X = x, \hat{\beta}) = \dfrac{1}{1 + \exp({-x^T\hat{\beta}})}$$

Comment: I think @DemetriPananos is missing a hat over the $\beta$ in the denominator above if you want to use standard notation.

Comment: Also then there should be some hat to indicate that $Pr( Y=1 \vert X = x)$ isn't a parameter

Comment: @user0 Again, it is all context dependent.  You can suppress explicit dependence on the coefficient so long as you are consistent.

Comment: Fair enough - appreciate your answer.  I still would not feel comfortable suppressing this particular notation because it's a hat